# Powerup variables in a platform game

Tags: pygame

I've made a platform game that has powerups in it. One of the powerups is a lightning bolt that is meant to increase your speed. However, when I tell it to increase the speed it increases it but makes my player move without use of pressing down my arrow keys. Any help? And I know you can't see it but I have included player.update, etc. in main, but I didn't show it, so the code would be shortened.

Thanks

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self,x,y,width = 65, height = 35):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.hspeed,self.vspeed = 0,0
    self.speed = 2
    self.Jump = 10

    self.images=[]
    r0 = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\i1.png")
    r1 = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\i2.png")
    r2 = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\i3.png")
    r3 = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\i4.png")
    self.hurt = pygame.image.load("Images\Player\Hurt.png")
    self.images.append(r0)
    self.images.append(r1)
    self.images.append(r2)
    self.images.append(r3)

    self.rotatedimages = []
    rr0 = pygame.transform.flip(r0 ,True, False)
    rr1 = pygame.transform.flip(r1 ,True, False)
    rr2 = pygame.transform.flip(r2 ,True, False)
    rr3 = pygame.transform.flip(r3 ,True, False)
    self.rotatedimages.append(rr0)
    self.rotatedimages.append(rr1)
    self.rotatedimages.append(rr2)
    self.rotatedimages.append(rr3)

    self.deadimages = [self.hurt]

    self.gravity = 0.35
    self.index = 0
    self.image = self.images[self.index]
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,width,height)

    self.TimeNum=0
    self.TimeTarget=10
    self.Timer = 0


def update(self, event = None):
    self.calcgravity()

    self.rect.x += self.hspeed
    self.rect.y += self.vspeed

    #Walking animation of animation when left or right key is pressed.
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if self.Timer >= 0:
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.TimeNum+=1
            if self.TimeNum == self.TimeTarget:
                self.index +=1
                if self.index >= len(self.images):
                    self.index = 0
                self.image = self.images[self.index]

                self.TimeNum = 0

        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.TimeNum+=1
            if self.TimeNum == self.TimeTarget:
                self.index +=1
                if self.index >= len(self.rotatedimages):
                    self.index = 0
                self.image = self.rotatedimages[self.index]
                self.TimeNum = 0
    # if you go outside the boundaries of the game.
    if player.rect.x < 0:
        GameOver()


 def move(self, hspeed, vspeed):
    self.hspeed += hspeed
    self.vspeed += vspeed


 def Level1Coll(self,PowerUps):

    PowerUpsCollision = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,PowerUps,True )
    for speedboost in PowerUpsCollision:
        self.speed = 3


def main()

GameExit = False

while GameExit==False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.move(-player.speed,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.move(player.speed,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.move(0,-player.Jump)
                JumpSound.play()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.move(player.speed,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.move(-player.speed,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.move(0,0)
```

Comment: this part of code looks good - and `speed = 3` doesn't change it - maybe show rest of code.

Comment: problem is because in one moment you add 2 to `hspeed/vspeed` and later you substract 3 so it give `hspeed = -1` or  `vspeed = -1` instead of `hspeed = 0` or  `vspeed = 0` - you have to (somehow) change `hspeed` and `vspeed` when you set `speed = 3`

Answer (score 1):

You set `self.speed` to be equal to 3, which usually means that the sprite will move on its own with a speed of 3. Instead create a new variable:

```
extra_speed = 0
```

and apply that to the increase of speed of the sprite:

```
self.rect.y += (self.vspeed + extra_speed)
```

Now when the sprite doesn't have the power-up, nothing changes as the speed increases by nothing. But when the sprite does get the powerup, simply change `extra_speed` to 3 and reset back to 0 when the sprite is finished with the power-up. To meet the problem of instant running, use another variable to determine when to run and use it before you check to run.

```
running = False
#A few lines later into your update function
if running:
    self.rect.x += self.hspeed
    self.rect.y += (self.vspeed + extra_speed)
```

The above code means that if `running` is True, then move the sprite appropriately. Otherwise, don't move the sprite.

Comment: if you set `extra_speed = 3` then you get `self.rect.y += (self.vspeed + 3)` so player will move even when `vspeed` is `zero`.

Comment: Thanks alot guys i implemented this after by key pressed conditional statements and it works like a charms!

Comment: You could click the green checkmark next to my answer if this is the best answer in your opinion